# Linear tween formula seems backwards

Tags: animation, graphics

I see this:

```
    float tweenLinear(float t, float start, float end)const{
    return t * start + (1 - t) * end;
}
```

`t` is the blend wait, between 0 and 1, the elapsed time / total duration of the animation.

But at the start of the animation, `t` will be 0, yet this returns `end`, not `start`, if `t` is 0.

Shouldn't this formula switch `start` and `end` in the return?

Comment: Thanks @RahulBanerjee. I'm always curious why people will answer the question as a comment, rather than as an answer, where I can accept it.

Comment: Ha! I agree with you, but in this case, there's no alternative. Answers must be above a certain word count (and my original answer was below that threshold).